# Why is the background image less smooth on the phone?

Tags: xna, image

I've just downloaded Gamestate code from [create.msdn.com](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management), and as you can see from the image below: [image]

The result is less smooth then the image imported to visual studio, how do I increase the quality?

Comment: Are you running your emulator in scaled mode? Try putting it at 100%. The other thing may be due to colors. This also may be part of the NoDo 16bit color banding issue: http://www.1800pocketpc.com/nodo-16-bit-color-banding-you-got-it-now-what-can-you-do-to-fix-it/19803/

Comment: same result on my phone and emulator @ 100%. will read thru the 16bit thingy

Comment: @Nate Boss read thru the 16bit NoDo thingy. First off: its no do, not recommendet. Second: i get this bug on my emulator, isnt that silly? Really breaks ALL my development, so i need a fix :(

Comment: The fix will come out later supposibly.  For now, all you can do is work with 16bit colors instead of 32.

Comment: @Jon Are u serious? That means no larger textures with a gradient will look nice at all on WP7? Im shocked... really.

Answer (score 4):

Set

```
graphics.PreferredBackBufferFormat = SurfaceFormat.Color;
```

in your `Game` constructor. XNA sets the backbuffer to `SurfaceFormat.Bgr565` (16 bit) by default.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get a better looking gradient by dithering the source image down to 565.

A quick search found [this Photoshop plugin](http://www.fragment.fi/2011/02/dithering-images-for-16-bit-displays/) that will do it, and some [instructions for doing it with ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=19349).